# Excel files not well formatted when downloaded from Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, azure, npoi

I'm building an ASP.NET WebForms application and I'm having a problem that I don't have a clue about what is causing It.

I'm using the NPOI C# library to generate Excel (.xls) files, and locally everything works fine, but I hosted the project on Azure, and when I download a spreadsheet, It is not beeing autosized, the columns are too thin for the cells content.

I have an endpoint that is called from an ajax request. It generate the spreadsheet returns an array of bytes that in the client-side I handle how the user will download It.

```
success: function(data) {
            var arr = data.d;
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
            var a = window.document.createElement('a');

            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }));
            a.download = 'myspreasheet';

            // Append anchor to body.
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();

            // Remove anchor from body
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
```

the NPOI method that autosize the columns is simple:

```
sheet.AutoSizeColumn(0);
sheet.AutoSizeColumn(1);
....
```

So, I don't guess It's a problem with measures culture, or something like.